# Android Creating seperate .apk while installing

Tags: android

This error randomly started happening after i made a new project and copied some files over.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fttech.hh.MenuActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.fttech.hh-1.apk]
```

As you see hh-1.apk should be hh.apk not hh-1.apk. But for some reason each time i try to load run it i get the ClassNotFoundError.

Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: The name of the APK file on the device has nothing to do with your problem. APKs are routinely renamed by Android, particularly during an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks but everything is in order..I cant figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

Yes I've seen this a while ago when debugging using my phone connected to eclipse.

I have no idea what caused it but in the end I simply manually un-installed the app from the phone, searched for any instance of the apk and the -1.apk and deleted them, cleaned the project and started again.

It didn't explain anything to me as to what caused it but it all started to work again and I haven't seen it happen since.

Comment: How Did You Search For the Apk's?

Comment: This issue has had my scratching my head ALL day!

Comment: Manually I'm afraid just using Astro to go through the SD card where I'd downloaded various things.